# ParseError syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE)

Tags: php

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "jaka_crud_ci";

mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

$query = "SELECT * FROM pembeli";
$result = mysqli_query($query)

while ( $buyer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $buyer ["nama_pembeli"];
echo $buyer ["nama_barang"];
echo $buyer ["nama_retribusi"];
}
?>
```

code above displaying  syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE). How it will be free from error? Help me

Comment: missing semicolon at the end of `$result = mysqli_query($query)`

Comment: An intelligent editor like Eclipse or NetBeans is advised. This will show error while we code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a semicolon at the end of

```
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

And you got the syntax wrong for mysqli_query, the correct one is, 
mysqli_query($connection_variable, $query)

So for your case it will be like,

```
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);
```

and then use it like,

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please update below line

```
$result = mysqli_query($query)
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

`;` is missing in that line. That's why the error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `;`   after `mysqli_query($query)` . Updated code is as below.

```
 <?php
    $server = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "jaka_crud_ci";

    mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM pembeli";
    $result = mysqli_query($query);

    while ( $buyer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $buyer ["nama_pembeli"];
    echo $buyer ["nama_barang"];
    echo $buyer ["nama_retribusi"];
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

its pretty simple syntax error,You are missing ; after mysqli_query($query)

You can also use the php command line options to check the sytax errors

```
php -l filename 

-l Provides a convenient way to perform only a syntax check on the given PHP code. On success, the text No syntax errors detected in <filename> is written to standard output
```

it will show if there any sytax error in the give filename

More Detail :http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

i hope this is helpful